# Trying to use 'FILTER' Function to write only on empty cells · GOOGLE SHEETS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I'm working on a personal project in google sheets related to a type of 'accounting' system of sort. pretty basic and just to organize myself.

Now, I'm trying to use the 'filter' function to write a series of cells in the same column when they meet certain criteria on another sheet, but I need to be able to write over the next available cell in the column, but doing so will render unusable the 'filter' function if the list on the other sheet grows, because would 'override data'.

There is a way to use the 'filter' function to jump over the wrote cells and write over the next available or empty cell?

The code I'm using is simple>

`=FILTER(BOD!A:A,BOD!E:E="house")`

being 'house' the criteria to write the cells of the sheet 'BOD' to the one I'm using.

Comment: not possible. instead of using FILTER use script. thats the only way

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output images you expect?

Comment: Please consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, clearly indicating the output you expect, or at least screenshots of this.